# Microsoft Exchange: Read/unread status individual to each user

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

We used to use IBM Notes at work, with multiple persons working out of one email-account. A big folder structure was created so that the information was correctly placed and retrievable. IBM Notes allowed a read/unread status for each individual person, so I could set an email to read and move it into a folder, but my colleagues would see the new email in that specific folder (with the folder being marked in bold letters as he has not read it). Therefor, all people knew about new emails, even if the emails were already in the folders. Folders which they did not require to read could just be ignored (leave the unread status) or just simply mark all emails in a folder and set to read.

Now we switched to Outlook and are using Microsoft Exchange accounts. Here, the logic is different. If one person sets an email to read, it is marked read on all accounts. This makes it problematic, so we can not simply move the email to the appropriate folder, as no one would know that a new email is actually in that folder.

Does anyone know a workaround? Using categories or tasks is not a good option. Also having the option of editing the mail and putting in a quick part so that everyone can mark the email separately as read is not an option, as this would lead to everyone having to check each folder.

I really miss IBM Notes in that regard, even though it is far more complicated than Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Per user read/unread status is only available for the Public Folders in Exchange, not for mailbox folders.

Comment: Is there a workaround for that? Due to the work organisation, we will remain on with a shared mailbox and can not transfer to public folders

Comment: You won't like the workarounds: https://exchange-server-guide.blogspot.com/2016/11/shared-mailbox-in-outlook-message-read-unread.html  
The only fix is switching to a PF store.

Comment: For crying out loud, what a bugger. Thank you nonetheless.